# Boot manager doesn’t see my ubuntu usb

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, uefi

I have installed windows 10 on uefi boot, now I want to install ubuntu alongside windows. The problem is that when i open boot manager computer cannot find ubuntu usb, but when i plug windows usb boot manager finds it. If i install everything on legacy then boot manager finds my ubuntu usb but when do ubuntu installation there is no option for “install ubuntu alongside windows 10”. Where could be a problem?

Comment: What brand/model system? Best to update UEFI and if SSD update SSD firmware. Make sure Windows fast start up is then off. Note Windows keeps turning it back on with major updates. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: I have tried all of them, but still UEFI mode doesn't find my usb with ubuntu, but for some reason boot manager can find my windows usb. I tried burning ubuntu into a different flash but still boot manager cannot locate my usb ubuntu. When I enter usb with ubuntu, boot manager shows Linpus Lite, but with windows usb I don't have that option. I have disabled fast boot as well as secure boot. I have the latest bios for my lenovo y700.

Comment: UEFI remembers installs, you have to manually remove UEFI entry if you have uninstalled Linpus Lite. You should be able to do that from UEFI or with efibootmgr once you are able to boot Ubuntu. What are you using to create USB flash drive? UEFI for USB always boots from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi, same for both Windows & Ubuntu but obviously bootx64.efi is different actual file.https://www.cnet.com/news/is-your-thinkpads-usb-c-port-not-working-upgrade-its-firmware/ You also need NVMe firmware update. And nomodeset boot parameter for nVidia.

Comment: I'm using Rufus to create flash drive

Comment: Are you using gpt & UEFI settings for Rufus, not UEFI(CSM) which is BIOS boot mode version? CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, only available with secure boot off.

Comment: Yes, i use gpt but it still doesn’t work

Comment: why does legacy boot find my usb but uefi doesn't?

Comment: I just noticed that when i changes rufus options from fat32 to ntfs then uefi boot manager sees my usb. Should i use ntfs and boot it like that?

Comment: I don't know how or why but when I changed rufus to etcher everything worked out fine

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the USB containing Ubuntu is bootable? I'd highly recommend following [this tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) since it is the recommended way of executing this process.

Once you've done that and the problem still occurs, then the boot order in your BIOS is probably incorrect. Therefore, you need to adjust the boot sequence priority in your BIOS. Go into your BIOS setup and select the BOOT tab. Afterwards, move the USB containing the Ubuntu image on top, thus giving it the highest priority on boot.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: The problem is that with uefi i can’t find my ubuntu usb

Comment: When i plug in my ubuntu usb I get a new option in boot manager linpus lite but with windows there is no linpus

Comment: That's just the name of the boot entry. That doesn't necessarily mean that the stick contains false data. Actually, some people have reported that writing Ubuntu to an USB with Rufus can cause this. That does not mean the data is malicious. Check [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/9pjpok/noob_question_ubuntu_bootable_usb_shows_as_linpus/).

Comment: I read that article before but what I found interesting is that when I first installed windows on Legacy mode and then tried installing ubuntu, boot manager saw my ubuntu usb, and it said USB ... and not Limpus, so that's why I think Linpus is the incoreect thing. But anyways, do you think I should try Linpus?

Comment: I'd fully format the USB, rewrite Ubuntu on it just to be 100% sure and then try it, yes.

Comment: I have fully reformated my usb like 10 times today, so I guess I will be trying Limpus

Comment: I have tried Linpus but then command line appeard but nothing happend for like 5 min. I trid entering somenthing but nothing changed

Comment: When I used rufus to create usb flass drive =, instead of fat32 I chose ntfs and then uefi boot manager found my usb, but when I try that usb gnu grub command line popped and now I don't know if what I'm doing is right or wrong way.